# Round up current time to next 30 mins interval

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want current time to round up to next 30 mins interval. Eg: If I open the app with current time as 8:33pm, I want next 30 mins round up time to be 9:00pm. If current time is May 22 11:30pm, next round up time should be May 23 00am.

I tried with below code, but that gives me the nearest round up which is 8:30pm.

How can I get next round up date and time?

```
func next30Mins() -> Date {
    return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / 1800.0).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) * 1800.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the date minute component, check if it is equal or more than 30 and return the nextDate with minute component equal to zero otherwise equal to 30:

```
extension Date {
    var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self) }
    var nextHalfHour: Date {
        Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(minute: minute >= 30 ? 0 : 30), matchingPolicy: .strict)!
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().nextHalfHour // "May 23, 2020 at 1:00 AM"
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the solution in my question with ceil and that worked... am not sure if it will turn 11:33pm to 00:00am... Yet to try. But I would like to try your solution too.

Here is what I did - Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: ceil(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / 1800.0).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) * 1800.0)

Comment: @tech_human I am not saying that your method doesn't work but you should always use the calendar methods to do your calendrical calculations. Btw readability is important as well.